# Using Xindy: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \cleardoublepage

Tags: macros, glossaries, itemize, xindy

I want to create a glossary in my article using [Xindy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xindy). I run this command in the TeXstudio:

```
xindy --language persian --codepage variant1-utf8 --input-markup xindy --module main --log-file main.fa.glg --out-file main.fa.gls main.fa.glo | xindy --language english --codepage utf8 --input-markup xindy --module main --log-file main.en.glg --out-file main.en.gls main.en.glo
```

The command is run without a problem. But when I compile my text, I get this error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \cleardoublepage
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \PrepareForLatinPages
```

Here is the section of glossary in `main.tex`:

```
% glossaries
{

\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1cm}
\printpersianglossary
\cleardoublepage
\printenglishglossary
}

\PrepareForLatinPages
```

I really don't know why I get this annoying error. The template I wrote my article using it, can be found here: [Sharif-Thesis](https://github.com/momeni/sharif-thesis)

Comment: It's _really_ hard to find what is wrong without seeing the code that is producing this error. Please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document that shows this error when compiled.

Comment: There is a template which I used it. I edited my post @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: You just need to download the template, add my command to TeXstudio, run it and compile the template. This is my _MWE_. @TeXnician

Comment: Sorry, I'll remove my comment. I did not notice it is GitHub, but usually I do not follow arbitrary links to code, because it is mostly not minimal.

Comment: As you know, I cannot write the whole template here. In this case, be sure that this is minimal. @TeXnician

Comment: I would be willing to download *one* file, the class. But I won't start to assemble your snippets here and snippets from the template to get a minimal example. It's up to you to post one here. Ensure that it doesn't rely on fonts not generally available and other external resources.

Comment: No, I compile it without the command. So, everything is true. But after running the command, I got the error when I compile. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: A *minimal* example is one that contains `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` that contains a minimal text document that demonstrates the problem. Code snippets aren't a MWE. If you're having difficulty creating one, try [Creating a LaTeX minimal example](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample).

Comment: I just downloaded the template and compiled it. I cannot write the whole template here as MWE. My minimal work is my command which I wrote in my question. If you want something like `\documentclass`, it is in the template, and as I said, I cannot write the whole template and its various files here. @NicolaTalbot

Comment: Don't use the template if you can't handle it and can't create a suitable minimal example. Or ask the author of the template to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the annoying problem. For the template, I used the command `\ترجمه` instead of `\LTRfootnote` or something else for writing footnote:

> \ترجمه{تست}{Test}